# É possível trocar a cor do cursor do mouse via CSS?

Tags: css, cursor

Eu sei que é possível trocar o estilo (tipo) do cursor do mouse via propriedade `cursor` no CSS. Mas, alguém sabe se é possível alterar a cor do cursor?

Em uma aplicação eu gostaria de ter o `pointer` cursor (a mãozinha apontando pra cima) em diferentes cores, dependendo do objeto sobre o qual o mouse for posicionado.

Já vi soluções em que o cursor é simplesmente escondido e utiliza-se Javascript para mover uma imagem representando o cursor desejado. Mas queria saber se há alguma solução mais trivial com as versões mais novas do CSS.

Comment: Por questões de usabilidade, é melhor não trocar o cursor do mouse. Deixa o cursor nativo do sistema operacional.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Apesar de você ter razão para alguns cenários, a aplicação que eu estou desenvolvendo é um jogo em que a seleção de cores faz parte da mecânica. Utilizar o mouse para indicar a cor selecionada me pareceu uma estratégia adequada (nos objetos com que o jogador interage - incluindo os botões de seleção de cor que mudam o mouse e têm indicação visual mutuamente exclusiva de estado "pressionado" - há diferentes símbolos para auxiliar pessoas com algum grau de daltonismo).

Comment: @Gabriel Santos, sua observação seria bacana caso o Luiz Vieira estivesse em dúvida ou demonstrasse uma preocupação quanto a usabilidade, do contrário, instruí-lo a não fazer o que ele deseja não agrega nada para uma solução do problema.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cor não é possível.

Porém você pode trocar o ponteiro do mouse com o CSS:

```
.novoCursos {
   cursor: url(ponteiroVermelho.gif), auto;
}
```

O código html ficaria assim:

```
<div class='novoCursos'>Ola, coloque o mouse em cima dessa frase para ver o cursor alterar.</div>
```

Comment: Só pra constar, parece que no IE só funciona se o ponteiro utilizado estiver no formato .cur (arquivo de cursor).

Answer (score 10):

Só pra adicionar uma outra informação bacana que eu encontrei (e um exemplo funcional!), eu resolvi criar esta resposta. :)

A partir [dessa thread do SO(en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408780/javascript-firefox-how-to-set-custom-cursor-from-local-png-file), eu aprendi que também é possível embutir o cursor diretamente no CSS via a codificação dos dados da imagem utilizada em `base64`. Com o auxílio de ferramentas online como [essa](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) ou [essa](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create), uma imagem de cursor submetida pode ser facilmente convertida em uma string de dados codificados.

Eu usei as seguintes imagens em formato PNG, criadas a partir [deste original de utilização livre](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-detail/2839):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codifiquei cada uma usando uma das ferramentas citadas, e utilizei a seguinte sintaxe para definir os cursores:

```css
cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...), auto;
```

[Este exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luigivieira/ZjPjm/) contém os dados codificados de cada uma das imagens de cursor acima e permite testar o funcionamento dessa sugestão.

A principal vantagem que eu imagino dessa utilização é justamente reduzir o número de requisições de recursos ao servidor. Procurando mais a esse respeito eu achei [essa outra thread no SO(en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258057/images-in-css-or-html-as-data-base64) que tem uma resposta muito bacana a respeito dos cuidados/limitações dessa abordagem. Traduzindo livremente abaixo:

> É uma boa prática comumente utilizada apenas para pequenas imagens em
>   CSS que serão utilizadas juntas (tal como *sprites*), quando a
>   compatibilidade com o IE não importa muito e, principalmente, quando a
>   economia nas requisições é mais importante do que a "cacheabilidade"
>   (imagens nesse formato não são mantidas em cache pelo navegador).
>
> Tem um número importante de pontos-negativos:
>
> - Não funciona de forma alguma no IE6 e no IE7.
> - Funciona para recursos de até 32k de tamanho no IE8. Esse é o limite que se aplica à codificação à representação após a codificação em
>     base64, ou seja, não se permite strings maiores do que 32.768
>     caracteres.
> - Economiza na requisição, mas carrega a página HTML! E impede o cache das imagens. Elas são carregadas toda vez que a página ou CSS contendo
>     a string codificada é carregada.
> - A codificação em base64 aumenta o tamanho das imagens em 33%.
> - Se for utilizado um recurso que compactado com gzip, isso causará um custo consideravel no servidor! Imagens tradicionalmente utilizam
>     muita CPU para serem comprimidas, com pouca compressão no tamanho.

EDIT: Eu fiz alguns testes aqui (windows 8.1 64bits) com o JSFiddle de exemplo. Funcionou perfeitamente no Chrome (32.0) e no Firefox (26.0), mas **não funcinou** no IE11.

EDIT2:

A solução da resposta do @LeandroAmorim **não funciona** no IE11 mesmo se for dada uma URL diretamente para um arquivo png ou gif. Depois de muito procurar, notei que pra isso funcionar no IE a imagem utilizada **deve estar no formato .cur ou .ani** (essa indicação de necessidade de usar o formato "cursor" para o IE está na especificação do CSS 2.1 referida na resposta do @Kazzkiq).

Como o formato de cursor é aceito pelos demais navegadores, pra funcionar de forma geral (*cross-browser*) basta utilizar sempre esse formato ao invés de png ou gif.

É bastante fácil obter os arquivos no formato .cur:

1. Via [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (por exemplo), salve as imagens no formato .ico;
2. Então, utilize [esse script Python](http://www.janthor.com/sketches/index.php?/archives/10-A-Python-script-to-convert-ICO-to-CUR-files.html) para converter os arquivos .ico em arquivos .cur;
3. Utilize no CSS os arquivos .cur da forma sugerida pelo @LeandroAmorim:

```css
cursor: url(red_pointer.cur), auto;
```

Eu só não consegui utilizar o cursor na abordagem de incluir os dados codificados em base64. Provavelmente porque não sei como identificar o tipo do formato dos dados (`data:image/x-icon` e `data:image/png` não funcionam...). Se alguém souber como fazer, agradeceria a indicação. :)

Answer (score 4):

Infelizmente, o cursor é uma propriedade do próprio OS (Windows, Linux, Apple). Por meio do CSS, consegue modificar o **tipo** de cursor, mas não a **cor** dele, pois a cor é definido nas configurações do OS.

Por isso que as soluções que você viu fez exatamente isso - esconder o cursor, e replicá-la de uma forma controlável pela JavaScript e/ou CSS.

**Atualização**

Como foi dito em algumas outras respostas, é possível usar seu próprio cursor, utilizando o atributo `url`, e usando um `.cur` ou `.gif`.

```
cursor:url('cursors/cursor.cur');
```

Algumas informações (em inglês) podem ser encontradas [aqui](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/), também explicando de alguns métodos de garantir 'cross-browser compatability'.

Answer (score 2):

Mudar somente a cor não é possível, contudo, a partir do [CSS 2.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url) é possível subistituir o cursor por um ícone:

```
body{ /*pode qualquer seletor válido*/
    cursor:url(cursor.gif), auto;
}
```

A opção `auto` é utilizada caso a imagem passada no parâmetro `url` apresente algum erro e não seja carregada.

Comment: Na verdade, não é possível **mudar a cor do cursor**, que nem a pergunta pede, mas sim **mudar a imagem** do cursos, como a sua solução propõe.

Comment: Você está certo @FelipeAvelar. Atualizei a resposta.