# Tamanho do cursor CSS

Tags: css

é possivel aumentar o tamanho (width e height) a partir do CSS, por exemplo

```
circle {
cursor:crosshair;
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Não. A não ser que você use uma imagem `cursor: url(cursor.gif), auto;`

Comment: Certo, como depois posso alterar o tamanho da imagem. E centrar no meio do ponteiro.

Comment: Definindo `width` e `height`, você quer centralizar um ponteiri? como assim?

Comment: Utiliwei o width e height e não m altera o seu tamanho. O cursor é activo quando passo em cima de um objeto, e aparece me mais em baixo.

Comment: Você pode colocar seu código completo com HTML e CSS desse cursor?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kyLuLshz/1/

Comment: So nao aparece a imagem nesse exemplo

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3653/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-trocar-a-cor-do-cursor-do-mouse-via-css

Answer (score 1):

Utilize uma imagem personalizada:

```
.ponteiro_personalizado {
   cursor: url(images/cursor.png), auto;
}
```